# Structure of Column Sums of Real Orthonormal Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, orthonormal, orthogonal-matrices

Suppose I have a square real orthonormal matrix $A \in O(D)$. I'd like to understand what structure exists in the set of column sums of $A$.

For instance, $O(2)$ can be parameterized by a single scalar. To see why, consider $A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$. Since the first column must have unit norm, $c = \sqrt{1 - a^2}$. Since the second column must be orthogonal to the first column and must also have unit norm, $b = -c$ and $d = a$. Consequently, $A = \begin{bmatrix} a & -\sqrt{1 - a^2}\\ \sqrt{1 - a^2} & a \end{bmatrix}$ and the column sums are $a + \sqrt{1 - a^2}$ and $a - \sqrt{1 - a^2}$. When I plot the column sums as a function of $a$, I observe these nice curves:

[image]

My question is: how does this structure generalize to $O(D)$? Is some quantity conserved? If I order the column sums in decreasing order, does some relationship between them hold?

Maybe what I'd like is some theorem that states "if the previous columns' sums were $A, B, C,...$ then the next column's sum is is equal to $Z$ / bounded between $[-X, Y]$"

Comment: It's just a little more complicated than that. You need to also consider whether $c > 0$ or $c < 0$. As it stands, you're missing out on half the orthogonal matrices by assuming $c > 0$.

Comment: The column sums of $A$ are just the entries of $e^TA$, where $e$ is the vector of ones. Hence they are the coordinates of some point on the sphere centred at the origin with radius $\sqrt{D}$.

Comment: @user1551 can I say anything beyond that? Since the vectors are orthonormal, it suggests that fixing one (or several) severely limits what remaining points on the sphere can be chosen.

Comment: @user854214 Good point! I hadn't noticed that. But it shouldn't affect the column sums, at least in the 2d case, should it (so long as we don't care about the order of columns)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing that the set of all possible column-sum-vectors [is a sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3929300/distribution-of-column-sums-of-orthogonal-matrix) essentially answers all possible questions you could want to ask about such vectors. Specifically, we have:

> Let $S(n)$ be the set of column-sum-vectors of orthogonal matrices in $O(n)$. Then $S(n)$ is equal to the sphere of radius $\sqrt n$ centered at the origin.

From the comments:

> can I say anything beyond that? Since the vectors are orthonormal, it suggests that fixing one (or several) severely limits what remaining points on the sphere can be chosen.

Bringing in the hypothesis that the vectors are orthonormal cannot possibly get you any stronger results, since that hypothesis is embedded in the theorem that the set of all column-sum-vectors is a sphere. So yes, fixing one or several coordinates restricts the others - but it restricts them only and precisely in that they must be chosen so that the resulting point ends up on a sphere. There is no point trying to get any further restrictions, as the result is that $S(n)$ is *equal* to a sphere - not a subset of it, and not a superset of it, but equal. Therefore the restriction is as tight as it gets.

For example:

1. You can parameterize $S(n)$, using any [standard parameterization of a sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates).
2. Yes, if you fix the first $k$ coordinates, this restricts the remaining coordinates since the whole vector must end up on a sphere. Specifically, the remaining coordinates $a_{k+1}, ..., a_n$ must be chosen so that
   $$a_{k+1}^2+...+a_n^2=n-(a_1^2+...+a_k^2)$$
   In other words, if $r^2=a_1^2+...+a_k^2$, the remaining coordinates must be chosen from a sphere of radius $\sqrt{n-r^2}$ in $(n-k)$-dimensional space.